# Exceptions handling in OCaml

Tags: exception, ocaml

I have to write the function `try_finalyze f g y x` of type : `('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> 'c -> 'a -> 'c`
knowing that:

**1.** if an exception is raised by `f x` the returned value has to be `y`

**2.** if `f x` doesn't raise any exception we have to return the result of `g` applied on `f x`

```
  exception E

    let try_finalyze f g y x = try g (f x) with E -> y;;

    val try_finalyze : ('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> 'c -> 'a -> 'c = <fun>
```

1.Is it right how I treated the problem?

2.In this context what will do the following function:

```
fun f -> try_finalyze f (fun x-> Some x) None
```

I don't see the role of a function like `(fun x-> Some x)`

Comment: Is requirement 2 fulfilled if `g f x` raises an exception and `f x` does not?

Comment: Your code assumes the exception is always E; I'm not sure if that's what's required. It's also not clear what you're supposed to do if `g` raises an exception. Your code returns y in this case.

Comment: I think I got it wrong exposed: the function  try_finalyze first applies f to x and then the scenario follows  rule 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write

```
let try_finalize f g y x = try g (f x) with _ -> y
```

Your function will return `y` if `f` doesn't raise an error but `g` does, which is not what you said you want.
To ensure that you catch only errors from `f` you should put `f x` alone in the try block:

```
let try_finalize f g y x =
  let z = try Some (f x) with _ -> None in
  match z with
  | Some z -> g z
  | None -> y
```

Exceptions may be considered bad style in a purely functional code, that's why you may want to transform a function that may raise an exception such as `List.assoc : 'a -> ('a * 'b) list -> 'b` into a function that does the same thing but returns an option.
That's what

```
let with_option f = try_finalize f (fun x-> Some x) None
```

does.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question is - not really. According to your specification function should catch any exception, not only your exception `E`. Maybe I'm misreading, but it will be better use the following definition:

```
let try_finalize f g y x = try g (f x) with exn -> y
```

As for the second part of the question, there're several ways in OCaml to signal an error. The two most common are:

1. Raise an exception
2. Return a value of an option type

The former variant is syntactically lighter, the later doesn't allow a caller to ignore the error condition. Sometimes you need to switch from one variant to an another. Suppose you have a function that raises an exception, and you would like to create a function with the same behavior, but returning an option value. Let's give it a name:

```
let with_option f = try_finalize f (fun x-> Some x) None
```

Then we can, for example, convert a `List.hd` to a function that returns an option type, depending on whether the list is empty or not:

```
let head x = with_option List.hd x
```

This function will have type `'a list -> 'a option`, compare it with `List.hd` type `'a list -> 'a`, the former will not allow to ignore the empty list case. When applied to an empty list, it will return a `None` value:

```
# head [];;
- : 'a option = None
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem statement correctly, I think I would do this :

```
let try_finalize f g y x =
  try
    let v = f x in g v
  with _ -> y
```

As for question 2, suppose you have a function f that takes a value of type v and computes a result of type r. This :

```
fun f -> try_finalize f (fun x-> Some x) None
```

returns a function that tries to apply `f`. If it succeeds (i.e. no exception is thrown), it returns `Some r`. Otherwise, it returns `None`. Basically, it transforms a function that may throw an exception into a function that will not throw anything. The new function returns a `r option` instead of a `r`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this but the function doesn't have anymore the required type

```
 let try_finalyze f g y x = match f x with
      |E -> y
      | _ -> g (f x) ;;
```